# How can I create and use a Makefile on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, makefile

I know how to write Makefiles for Linux, and was hoping it would be similar in Windows. However, from what I've seen on the internet, it is quite difficult.

If I have one file `main.cpp`, what would be the simplest form of a Makefile? Also, what would be the command to `make Makefile` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Go get your [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on. Given your experience with *nix `make`, this might be the path of least resistance.

Comment: I would like to keep it barebones Windows though. Do you know how to make a simple Makefile that does `main.o` as well as `clean: ` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief...

```
$ ls && cat main.cpp && cat Makefile && make && ./main
Makefile main.cpp
/* main.cpp */
#include <iostream>
int main(int, char **) {
  std::cout << __func__ << "@" << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
# Makefile
all: main
clean: ; rm -f main
g++     main.cpp   -o main
main@main.cpp:4
$
```

That's as bare-bones as I can make it.

Comment: In my Cygwin shell I had to specify `tree.com`. Perhaps @rubicks has an alias for `tree`.

Comment: Whoops, my bad; I forgot not everyone has [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/). I've amended to use `ls` instead.